# Inspect in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I use this code:

```
x = []
x << 1

if (x[0].inspect == 1) 
  puts "OLLAAA"  
end
```

It outputs nothing, but it should because `x[0].inspect` is `==` to `1`. But if I change `==` to `!=` I get output `"OLLAAA"`, or when `if` is changed to `unless`. Any ideas?

Comment: 1.inspect => "1", not 1.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes you are right.

Comment: thx to all -), it was a bit confusing. i just add .to_i, x[0].inspect.to_i == 1, it works -)

Comment: @igrach `x[0].inspect.to_i` is identical to `x[0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fixnum#inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-inspect) is an alias for `to_s` - you need to compare against `"1"`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you so sure `x[0].inspect == 1`?  [`Object::inspect` returns a string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect).

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p247 :001 > x = []
 => [] 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > x << 1
 => [1] 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > x[0].inspect == 1
 => false
```

If you change `==` to `!=`, obviously you flip the logic, so it prints.  The exact same thing is happening for `if` to `unless`.

Answer (score 2):

Because of below :

`x[0].inspect # => "1"`

`x[0].inspect` gives string instance,which is not equal to `Fixnum` instance 1. Thus `x[0].inspect == 1` evaluates to `false`,and you didn't get the output. Now when you use `!=`,hope you got the point why you did get the output.

`Fixnum#inpect` call actually does `Fixnum#to_s`. See below :

```
12.method(:inspect) # => #<Method: Fixnum#to_s>
```

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above, inspect return a string. You can solve your problem with

```
if (x[0].inspect.to_i == 1)
  puts "Hey I am an integer :)"
end
```